# How can I show following sequence of square root is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nested-radicals

For positive $p$

$$\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p+\cdots}}}}=x$$

I want to show that this is convergent by using contractive mapping.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See also these posts: [Proof $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2}}}}=2$ using Banach's Fixed Point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165027/proof-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt2-2) and [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 1):

You have $x=\sqrt{p+\text{something}}$, and "something" is equal to $x$ itself.  So

$$
x = \sqrt{p + x}. \tag 1
$$

Thus $x$ is a fixed point of the mapping $$w\mapsto \sqrt{p+w}. \tag 2$$  We can ask whether that mapping is a contraction.

$$
\frac d {dw} \sqrt{p+w} = \frac{ 1 }{2 \sqrt{p+w}}.
$$

If the absolute value of the derivative remains less than some number $c<1$, then we can use the mean value theorem to show that this is a contraction.  The derivative is less than $c$ iff $2\sqrt{p+w} > 1/c$, and that means $p+w > 1/(4c^2)$.  Thus on the interval

$$
\left( \frac 1 {4c^2} - p, \infty \right) \tag 3
$$

the mapping $(2)$ is a contraction, and thus must have exactly one fixed point in that interval.

If we square both sides of $(1)$ we get a quadratic equation
$$
x^2 - x - p = 0.
$$
The solutions are
$$
x = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{ 1+4p }} 2.
$$

Is exactly one of those inside the interval $(3)$?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. Would you mind explaining more about why derivative less than 1 implies contractive mapping?

Comment: The way my professor defined Contraction is that  IF(x)-F(y)I is less than or equal to cIx-yI for all x, y  on given interval. Is there any relationship between this definition and derivative less than 1?

Comment: A derivative everywhere less than $1$ does not imply a mapping is a contraction, but a derivative everywhere less than or equal to some particular number less than $1$ does imply that.  The mapping $x \mapsto \sqrt{1+x^2}$ has a derivative whose absolute value is everywhere less than $1$, but there is no number $c<1$ for which the absolute value of the derivative is everywhere less than or equal to $c$.  That is because the derivative approaches $1$ as $x\to\infty$.  And that mapping is not a contraction and has no fixed point.  [continued below] ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Suppose $|f'(x)| \le c < 1$ everywhere.  Then the mean value theorem implies $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(\cdots)$ and the absolute value of the derivative is $\le c$.  That imples $|f(x) - f(y)| \le c|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.  That is the definition of a contraction. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Does it matter whether starting point of the sequence is not contained in the interval you found? for instance let starting point of the sequence be 0. However, 0 is not contained in the interval.

Comment: The reason why I am asking this is that in my book, "Let C be closed interval and F is contractive mapping of C, then F has a unique fixed point. Moreover, this fixed point is the limit of every sequence with a starting point contained in C"